# About the Environment Variables and init in linux

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

In linux, some program/process is created by the init, and also those process also need to set some Environment Variables.

I think, when the init start to run, the shell just don't started.

So, How can the init set the Environment Variables without a shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Environment variables can be exported from a process to its parent(s) then is then inherited to other children and grand children including the shell

Comment: so, the concept of Enviroment variables belongs to OS not the shell? then there must be some API to get and set Enviroment var, is it?